# Qt Quick Application problem with version

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm trying to create a simple new project with Qt Creator (open source) that I just installed (so clean installation) but when I try to create a new project (in particular a Qt Quick Application) I can just build it for Qt version I don't have installed (6.x+), here a screen:

[image]

If I choose one of them I had this:
[image]

but what I have installed, from Qt Maintence tool is just this and I can't choose my Qt Version (5.12):

[image]

This is my kit view:
[image]

How can I solve?

I tried, several times, to unistall and reinstall.

Comment: Sounds like a Qt Creator bug. (Obviously they want you to upgrade to the newest version of Qt.) What version of Creator are you using?

Comment: Qt Creator 11.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select **Qt Quick Application (compat)** to be able to use older Qt versions. This screenshot is from Qt Creator 12.0.1, but this was there in older versions as well.

[image]